# How can I write a user assigned variable to a list of URLs in a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a text file containing a list of multiple urls `list.txt`. I am trying to add a variable to each of the search strings in this list so that a line like `https://www.google.com/search?q=` would be appended with the variable `"$v"` or its correct equivalent to look like `https://www.google.com/search?q="$v"`

My goal is to do something like the code below so that every time the script is executed the variable in `list.txt` can be redefined. But I can't seem to figure out how to make `"$v"` in `list.txt` be interpreted as the variable assigned by the user.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter you query"
read -p "" v

cat list.txt | while read urls; do 
lynx -dump -listonly -get_data "$urls"; done
```

Edit - It should be noted that for some of the urls in this list the search string is not at the end of the line. For example `http://example.com/?s="${v}"&x=0&y=0` where `"{v}"` is the variable I'm trying to place.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to use `curl` or `wget` for that?  Invoking a browser to resolve a URL seems like overkill.

Comment: The idea is really more about generating a list of direct links specific to the individuals needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` can handle this without loops

```
$ cat urls

http://example.com/q={v}&x=0
http://example.com/q=1&r={v}&z=0

$ v=foo; sed "s/{v}/$v/" urls

http://example.com/q=foo&x=0
http://example.com/q=1&r=foo&z=0
```

specify the location of the variable with a marker (here `{v}`) and do the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this:

```
lynx -dump -dump -listonly -get_data "${urls}${v}"
```

`"${urls}${v}"` will be `https://www.google.com/search?q=` plus `foo`  (if `foo` was the user input).

**Simple Example**

The input

```
$ cat urls.txt 
http://example.com/q=
http://example.com/r=
```

The variable:

```
$ v=foo
```

Loop:

```
$ cat urls.txt| while read url
do
  echo "${url}${v}"
done
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/q=foo
http://example.com/r=foo
```

Comment: As a general rule, I prefer the auto-escaping capabilities of `xargs` for iterating over file contents like this, mainly because it has very sane handling of whitespace.  But in this case, since URLs need to escape whitespace anyway, this should work.  Be aware though, if `$v` does need to be URL Encoded, this wouldn't work properly.  I'm guessing that isn't a concern in this event.

Comment: That would work if every search string were at the end of the line but some of the urls are like `http://example.com/?s="${v}"&x=0&y=0` and `http://example.com/search.php?from=&new=&q="${v}"&qcat=foo`. My fault for not properly stating that in the question.

Comment: The order of query params does not matter. You can always put `$v` at the end of every URL.